# Can someone explain to me what stty does?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

I have a shell script inside Docker. This is not mine, unfortunately I get the following error when running it. But only under Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker 19.03.

**stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device**

Here a cutout of line 126 from the script. What makes the stty echo and stty -echo? And why does the script run without problems on an system without docker?

```
askNoEcho() {
  PROMPT=$1
  DEFAULT=$2

  stty -echo
  ask "$PROMPT" "$DEFAULT"
  stty echo
  echo ""
}

askNonBlankNoEcho() {
  PROMPT=$1
  DEFAULT=$2

  while true; do
    stty -echo
    ask "$PROMPT" "$DEFAULT"
    stty echo
    echo ""
    if [[ -n "$response" ]]; then
      break
    fi
    echo "A non-blank answer is required"
  done
}
```

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html

Comment: This is a common generic message, which is annoying but causes no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$ stty echo < ~/tmp/some.file
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

so, `stty` expects its standard input to be a terminal.

Therefore, if you run on your terminal

```
$ stty echo
```

you will receive no errors.

Answer (score 3):

`stty` sets the terminal modes on the terminal connected to stdin.  If stdin is not a terminal (eg, it's been redirected from a file when running your script), then it will display the error you show

`stty -echo` turns off echoing of input keystrokes.  Normally when you type in a terminal, the characters you type are echoed back so you can see what you typed.  `stty echo` turns echoing back on.  The net effect is to disable echoing for the line entered in response to the prompt -- so it will print a prompt and wait for input, (and return the input), but that input will not be visible on the screen.  This is commonly done for entering a password or passphrase.

There are many other terminal modes and settings that can be changed or queried with `stty` with various arguments.  The manual page (`man stty`) will give you lots of additional info.